# What does "20"[1] do?

Tags: c, arrays, array-indexing

In a test exam, we were told to find the value of some expressions.

All but 1 were clear, which was `"20"[1]`. I thought it was the 1st index of the number, so `0`, but testing with a computer it prints `48`.

What exactly does that 'function' do?

Comment: *"I thought it was the 1st index of the number, so 0,"* You're right. It's the `char` `'0'`, and if you look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll find that its value (as an integer) is `48`.

Comment: `'0'` is 0x30 or 48 in ASCII

Comment: `a[b]` is syntactical sugar for *(a+b) in c.

Comment: It does the same thing as `1["20"]`. :)

Comment: @IanAbbott Or `true <: "\62\60" ??)??' false`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a function, it's just indexing an array.

`"20"` here is a character array, and we're taking the value at index 1 - which is `'0'` - the character `'0'`.

This is the same as

```
char chArr[] = "20";       // using a variable to hold the array 
printf ("%d", chArr[1]);   // use indexing on the variable, decimal value 48
printf ("%c", chArr[1]);   // same as above, will print character representation, 0
```

The decimal value of `'0'` is `48`, according to [ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/), the most common encoding around these days.

Comment: The fun question would be **What's the value of "20"[2]?** :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica The fun answer would be "Pizza in 30 minutes...prepaid!!" :)

Comment: Not if it means I'd have to be at work late in order to get the "free" pizza. :-(

Comment: Why is that a *fun* question? `"20"` is an array with 3 elements, so `"20"[2]` returns the last element.

Comment: @thebusybee - it's "fun" because it returns something you can't see. It's the kind of trick question interviewers (seem to) love.

Comment: and, many would miss the fact that the array length is actually 3.

Comment: Well, actually I *can* see it. ;-) It depends on *how* you try to see it: "%d" prints a "0", redirected output of "%c" and loaded in Notepad++ shows `NUL`, and so on... But you're right in so far that most beginners have difficulties to make it visible.

Answer (score 3):

Well, depending on your point of view it's either `'0'`, 48, or 0x30.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
  printf("'%c' %d 0x%X\n", "20"[1], "20"[1], "20"[1]);

  return 0;
  }
```

The above prints

```
'0' 48 0x30
```

Answer (score 1):

In this subscripting expression

```
"20"[1]
```

"20" is a string literal that has the type `char[3]`. Used in expressions the literal is converted to pointer to its first element.

So this expression

```
"20"[1]
```

yields the second element of the string literal that is `'0'`.

You can imagine this record like

```
char *p = "20";

char c = p[1];
```

`48` is the ASCII value of the character `'0'`.

A more exotic record can look like

```
1["20"]
```

that is equivalent to the previous record.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postﬁx expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   deﬁnition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "\"20\"[1] == '%c' and its ASCII value is %d\n", "20"[1], "20"[1] );
    printf( "1[\"20\"] == '%c' and its ASCII value is %d\n", 1["20"], 1["20"] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
"20"[1] == '0' and its ASCII value is 48
1["20"] == '0' and its ASCII value is 48
```